# Issue with saving in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am getting a certain value called `productId` from the api. I want to store this value in Core-Data so that I can use this in another view-controller.

So when I'm getting the `productID` from the api, this is how I'm saving it...

```
    ....else if result["success"] as! Int == 1 {
           print("SUCCESS!!")                         
           self.productId = (result["product_id"] as! NSString) as String
           self.saveId(givenName: self.productId) //Saving here...
}
```

In the `saveId` function, this is what I'm doing...

```
    func saveName(givenName:String) {

     //Saving to CoreData
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Category", in: managedContext)

        let category = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)

        category.setValue(givenName, forKey: "productId")

        do {

            try managedContext.save()
            self.mangObjArr.append(category as! Category)
            } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
     }
```

This is not working because in `viewWillAppear` when I fetch the data, I'm getting nil for `productId`. This is what I'm doing in `viewWillAppear`...

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Category")
        if let fetchedObjects = try? managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest), !fetchedObjects.isEmpty
        {
            let category = fetchedObjects.first as? NSManagedObject

            self.theProductId = category?.value(forKey: "productId") as! String
            print(theProductId)
        }
```

Hope somebody can help...:)

Comment: Isn't using Core Data for saving one simple value a bit overkill? Moreover, if you are storing it only to allow using it across viewControllers.. Isn't using `UserDefaults` a better idea in this case?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ But even if I stop my app and then run it some other day, even then I should have that value...can userDefaults do that..? I mean storing something indefinitely...?

Comment: it will store it until you delete the app from the phone, so persistence-wise they are comparable with Core Data

Comment: OK @MilanNosáľ But will deleting the app from the phone also cause Core Data values to be wiped out...?

Comment: I believe so.. As far as I know, they are saved in the App folder, thus they get deleted along with the app. I haven't done it, but I believe you would have to synchronize this data with the iCloud, or store them somewhere on your own server..

Comment: although it of course depends on where is your Core Data storage - I am talking about most common default case when it is stored in the app folder, but I believe you can have core data storage on iCloud ( https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/DesignForCoreDataIniCloud.html ) and in that case deleting the app would not wipe out data (unless the user does not explicitly wipe out also the icloud)

Comment: @MilanNosáľ so you are suggesting using UserDefaults is a proper method...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157546/discussion-between-milan-nosa-and-bws).

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching the data from CoreData of entity category.
Check whether category object is nil or not before checking the productId.

If your category object is nil than it is obvious that productId is nil and this is because your fetching category from CoreDB and there is no record for that entity.

Hope you understand.

Save data before fetch will return you some record.